# Dropbox Core API 413 error on creating a share link

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api, http-status-code-413

Im currently trying to create a share links for a pdf file that was just uploaded through my App while using the Dropbox Core API.

The code is below:

```
request.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/shares/auto/proposals/'+name+'?short_url=false',{
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN HERE', 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        },body:content}, function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, bodymsg) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    }else{
            console.log('Shared link ' + JSON.stringify(httpResponse));
}
});
```

**Points to note:**

1. The PDF file size is 11MB, I can successfully and easily upload the file to dropbox using the API.
2. The issue only arises when I try to create a share link for the recently uploaded 11MB file.
3. Also note I am using Node.JS to upload & create share links.

**The Error:**

The error I get is HTTP Error 413, which based on my research means "**Request entity too large**"

Below is an image of the error, its not the whole image as the error was too long:

[image]

The maximum file size for uploading through the API is 150MB and my file is way below the line. Is there a separate file size for generating share links?

**Note**

I have tested small files of size 1MB to 2MB and was successfully able to generate a share link, issue arises with large files i.e (11MB)

Comment: What's the value of `content`? 413 would suggest you're sending a lot of data to Dropbox, but [`/shares`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares) only takes up to two parameters (`locale and `short_url`), and those should both be small. Also, you're sending `application/pdf` as a `Content-Type`, but this method expects a form post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you're sending a body and using a `Content-Type` of `application/pdf`, I'm going to guess that you're trying to upload a file with this API call, but that's not what [`/shares`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares) does. `/shares` is a way to create a shared link to a file that's already in Dropbox. You should upload with, e.g. [`/files_put`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put), and then call `/shares` to create a shared link to that file.